# How to determine if conditional expectations with respect to different measures are equal a.s.?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $Q_{\mathcal{A}}$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and define, for all $P$-integrable $f$,
$$Q(f) := \int E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A})dQ_{\mathcal{A}}.$$

Note that $E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A})$ is the conditional expectation with respect to $P$. Also note that $Q$ defines a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ by taking $f$ to be an indicator function (we abuse notation by writing $Q(A)$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}$).

**Motivation.** The idea is that we start with a "prior" probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. This extends to a linear functional (expectation) on the space $L^1$ of $P$-integrable functions $f$. Then we "learn" something about the sub-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and adopt the new probability $Q_{\mathcal{A}}$ defined on $\mathcal{A}$. The question arises: How to extend this new probability $Q_{\mathcal{A}}$ to all of $\mathcal{F}$ (and thereby $L^1$)? We consider the extension $Q$ defined above.

**Question.** Does $E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A}) = E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A})$ a.s. ($P$)?

**Added Question.** Is $Q \ll P$?

The a.s. equality would follow if I could show that $$\int_A E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A}) dP = \int_A f dP$$
for all $A \in \mathcal{A}.$ But I'm not sure what can be said when integrating a $Q$-conditional expectation against the measure $P$.

---

I believe I can show the result for the case where $\mathcal{A}$ is generated by a countable partition $\{A_i \}_{i \in I}$ with $P(A_i)>0$ and $Q_{\mathcal{A}}(A_i) > 0$ for all $i \in I$.

In that case, we have
$$E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A}) = \sum_i E_Q(f \mid A_i) \mathbf{1}_{A_i},$$
so it suffices to show that $E_Q(f \mid A_i) = E_P(f \mid A_i)$ for all $i \in I$.

To that end we calculate (I abuse notation, writing $A_i = \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$)
$$\begin{align} E_Q(f \mid A_i) &= \frac{1}{Q(A_i)} \int_{A_i}fdQ \\
 &= \frac{1}{Q(A_i)} \int E_P(fA_i \mid \mathcal{A}) dQ_{\mathcal{A}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{Q(A_i)} \int \left(\sum_{j \in I} \mathbf{1}_{A_j} \frac{1}{P(A_j)} \int_{A_i}fA_j dP \right)dQ_{\mathcal{A}} \\
&= \frac{Q_{\mathcal{A}}(A_i)}{Q(A_i)} \frac{1}{P(A_i)} \int_{A_i} f dP \\
&= E_P(f \mid A_i).\end{align}$$

The problem with extending this to general $\mathcal{A}$ is that I can't say explicitly what the conditional expectations (almost surely) are.

Comment: How do you define $E_Q(f\mid \mathcal{A})$?

Comment: As I mentioned, $Q$ determines a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. I was hoping I could be harmlessly ambiguous by calling that measure $Q$ as well. Then $E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A})$ is the $Q$-conditional expectation of $f$ given $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I see. Also a.s. equality (between conditional expectations) is w,r.t. to what measure? It's not clear in the case when $P\mid_\mathcal{A}$ is not equivalent to $Q_\mathcal{A}$ so that $P$ is not equivalent to $Q$...

Comment: Edited, thanks. I meant $P$-almost surely.

Comment: It appears that you need the condition $P|\mathcal{A} = Q_{\mathcal{A}}$.

Comment: @Gordon I'd be interested to see a proof that $P |\mathcal{A} = Q_{\mathcal{A}}$ is a necessary condition. If it's not though, I'm not really interested in focussing on that case because it's trivial.

Comment: That wold be trivial as $Q|\mathcal{A} = Q_{\mathcal{A}}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very interesting question, because it leads to a useful discussion on matters, which usually are overlooked when one speaks of conditional expectations.

The first thing to note is that one should be extremely careful with writing things like 
$$
E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A}) = E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A}) \tag{1}
$$
for some measures $P$ and $Q$ (with $Q$ not necessarily defined as in the OP). The sad truth is that the conditional expectation $E_Q(f \mid \mathcal{A})$ is defined modulo $Q$-null sets. This makes equality (1) totally meaningless *unless the measures $Q$ and $P$ have the same null sets, i.e. they are equivalent*.

Now turning to the particular situation, $E_{Q_{\mathcal A}}(E_P(f\mid\mathcal A))$ cannot be defined if $Q_{\mathcal A}\not\ll P|_{\mathcal A}$. Indeed, in this case case there is some $A\in\mathcal A$ with $Q_{\mathcal A}(A)>0 = P(A)$. Changing the values of $E_P(f\mid\mathcal A)$ on $A$ does not change this conditional expectation. However, it does change the value of $E_{Q_{\mathcal A}}(E_P(f\mid\mathcal A))$.

Consequently, we *must* assume that $Q_{\mathcal A}\ll P|_{\mathcal A}$. Moreover, if $P|_{\mathcal A}\not \ll Q_{\mathcal A}$, then (1) cannot hold $\pmod P$. Indeed, in this case there is some set $B\in\mathcal A$ such that $P(B)>0 = Q(B)$. Then we can change the left-hand side of (1) on $B$ arbitrarily. On the bright side, (1) does hold $\pmod Q$ even in this case. To show this, note that by definition of $E_Q(\cdot\mid\mathcal A)$, (1) holds iff for any $A\in \mathcal A$ 
$$
E_Q(A\,f ) = E_Q(A\,E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A})).
$$
But 
$$
E_Q(A\,f) = Q(A\, f) = E_{Q_{\mathcal{A}}}(E_P(A\,f \mid \mathcal{A})) \\ = E_{Q}(E_P(A\,f \mid \mathcal{A})) = E_{Q}(A\,E_P(f \mid \mathcal{A})),
$$
as required.

The answer to the second question is positive (but, I repeat, you must assume $Q_{\mathcal A}\ll P|_{\mathcal A}$). Indeed, if $P(A) = 0$, then $E_P(A\mid\mathcal A) = 0 \pmod P$ thanks to the tower property, therefore, $E_P(A\mid\mathcal A) = 0 \pmod Q_\mathcal A$ in view of the absolute continuity, so
$$
Q(A) = E_{Q_{\mathcal{A}}}(E_P(A\mid \mathcal{A})) = 0,
$$
as claimed. (Alternatively, you can just show, by definition, that $dQ/dP = dQ_{\mathcal A}/dP|_{\mathcal A}$.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful answer. I'll need to sit down with this later today and study it more carefully.

Comment: I think I follow your reasoning, but "$=\{ Q = Q_{\mathcal{A}} \text{ on } \mathcal{A}\}$" looks like a typo.

Comment: @aduh, I mean that the equality is true because $Q|_{\mathcal A} = Q_{\mathcal A}$.

Comment: Right, okay. But saying that the $E_{Q_{\mathcal{A}}}$ expectation _equals_ $\{ Q = Q_{\mathcal{A}} \text{ on } \mathcal{A}\}$ doesn't make sense to me. Is $\{ Q = Q_{\mathcal{A}} \text{ on } \mathcal{A}\}$ a number, a function, a set? Anyway, it's not terribly important; the reasoning is clear.

Comment: Could we have $E_Q(f) = E_{Q_{\mathcal{A}}}(E_{P}(f \mid \mathcal{A}))$ without $Q_{\mathcal{A}} \ll P|_{\mathcal{A}}$? I take your point that we need this assumption to ensure that $Q$ is well defined. But we couldn't the equality happen to hold in some cases in which absolute continuity fails?

Comment: @aduh, I don't understand your last question. There is no $Q$ if $Q_{\mathcal A}\not\ll P|_{\mathcal A}$. What equality do you want to have in this case?

Comment: @aduh, it seems that you are missing the main point. I've edited the answer trying to make it clearer. In short, your last question sounds like "Could we have such an extension (and call it $Q$) such that $Q(f) = 0/0$?" This question makes no sense, since $0/0$ cannot be defined.

Comment: @aduh, I don't know what else to say. Just reread the third paragraph (I've changed it a little bit).

Comment: Great, thank you again for your patience and helpful answer. I pressed because I'm reading a paper where the authors seem to claim that the absolute continuity isn't always required. I'll have to try to better understand what they have in mind.

Comment: @aduh, can you provide a link?

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-016-1070-8. See remark 4 in section 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48347/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-aduh).